# Strip commas from input value

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm trying to add a class to the checkboxes in Contact Form 7 based from the value of the individual checkbox.

So far i've got it so it's adding the value as a class but i can't seem to get rid of the commas.

I've tried this but it's not working. Can anyone help please?

```
$( "#select-skip-form input[type=checkbox]" ).addClass(function(index) {
     return $(this).val().replace(/,/g,'').toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
});
```

EDIT

So for example i have a checkbox with the value "7 yard enclosed 'builders' skip" and i want to add this as a class on the field without the commas or spaces.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-355" value="7 yard enclosed &#039;builders&#039; skip" />
```

So it ends up being like this:

```
   <input type="checkbox" class="7-yard-enclosed-builders-skip" name="checkbox-355" value="7 yard enclosed 'builders' skip" />
```

Comment: Can you provide an example value? What you have and what you want?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question with the example. Thanks :)

Comment: There are no commas in `7 yard enclosed 'builders' skip`. Do you mean you want to remove the apostrophes?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear. He wants `7 yard enclosed &#039;builders&#039; skip` class to become this `7-yard-enclosed-builders-skip`. I only wonder how do you even got that in there in the first place?!...

Comment: Apologies, yes i meant apostrophes!! Stupid me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $value = $('input').attr('value');
$value=$value.replace(/[^\/|\/a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
$value=$value.split(' ').join('-');
console.log($value);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xeaLbkh/1/

Comment: Nice. Your Welcome :)